# Symfony2 forum integration?

Tags: php, symfony, forum

I have a functioning Symfony2 website with authentication and users provided through FOSUserBundle.

What would be the best and easiest way to integrate a forum with the existing users table, preserving the current registration, login, and account information workflows?

Edit:

Yes, a forum such as phpBB3, thanks.

Comment: What kind of forum are we talking about? Something like phpBB or a hosted one? This question is way to generic to give precise answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://vanillaforums.org

https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla - on Github (I've used 2.1 branch)

https://github.com/tgalopin/TgaForumBundle - bundle for integration Vanilla into Symfony2